# Django URL and Template with inbuilt authentication

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I am a Django Beginner, I started by reading WS Vincent..The book created a customUser model in a separate App name USERS. Also, AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser' has been set up. I have below question related to URLS and Templates . Any help will be appreciated
I have been reading that the Default Django login path will go to /accounts/login. However , when I used {% url login %} in template base.html it routed to users/login. That would be coz fo Auth_user_model, but I want to be sure how the above tag would fit in below URL's because there is still no accounts/login URL. If it is getting that from auth.urls package then it only has everything starting with /accounts not /user. I did a packet capture thinking it might be translating to account/login but destination was still users/login. .I hope I was able to explain my query. Please help.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')), # new
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),# new
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'),name='home'), # new
```

]

Answer (score 0):

(if i understand your question correctly) there is a default value in settings.py which you have to override
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGIN_URL